# なぜここにオプショナル型？

Tags: swift, swift3, optional

画面移動のコードを書きたくて

```
@IBAction func goSecond(_ sender: Any) {
    　　let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
    　　present(secondVC!, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

ボタンと接続させるコードを書いたんですが、`present(secondVC!~....`の、`secondVC`に`!`がつくのかよく理解できません。オプショナル型にすれば解決することはわかったのですが、これからも頻発しそうなエラーなので具体的な理由を教えていただけないでしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

あなたのコードのこの行:

```
let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
```

使用している`instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`メソッドの戻り値型はオプショナルではない`UIViewController`と定義されていますが、そのメソッドはオプショナルチェイニング(`?.`)の中で呼び出されています。

オプショナルチェイニングでは、`?.`の左辺の`self.storyboard`が`nil`だった場合、式全体として`nil`を返さないといけないので、`self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")`という式の戻り値型はオプショナルの`UIViewController?`になるのです。

従って、それを初期値として宣言された`secondVC`のデータ型も`UIViewController?`となり、オプショナルが許されていない場所で使うためには強制アンラップ(`!`)等の対処が必要になるわけです。(`secondVC`のデータ型がどのように型推論で決定されたかは、カーソルをそこにおいてXcodeの右サイドバーにあるQuick Helpを見れば表示されます。)

---

ちなみに強制アンラップの`!`は、「100%絶対に`nil`にならないという自信があるとき以外は使わないこと」というのはご存知かと思いますが、最終的に強制アンラップを行う必要があるのでしたら、できるだけ早めに適用した方が、想定外の`nil`のせいでアプリがクラッシュした時に、そもそもの`nil`が発生した場所を突き止めやすくなります。

```
@IBAction func goSecond(_ sender: Any) {
　　let secondVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "second")
　　present(secondVC, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

こちらのコードでは、`secondVC`のデータ型は非オプショナルの`UIViewController`となるので、`present(_:animated:completion:)`メソッドを呼ぶ際には`!`が要らないということになります。

---

(蛇足ながらコメントの一部を本文に移動させました。)

もしご自分で十分調べる前にご質問いただいたのであれば、今後は事前に十分お調べの上で解決でき‌​ない場合にご質問いただくようにお願いしま‌​す。

とは言え今回の内容はオプショナルが絡‌​むということ以外にはうまくキーワードを選‌​ぶのが難しいため、なかなか思うような記事‌​にヒットしなかったかもしれません。

オンラ‌​インで情報を探す時のコツですが、

- 「オプ‌​ショナル」などのキモになる用語はできるだ‌​け正確に使用する
  (残念ながらSwift用‌​語には定訳と言えるものがないので、英単語‌​のOptionalの方が良いかもしれませ‌​ん。それでもちゃんとたくさん日本語の記事‌​が出てきます。)
- エラーになる場合は、エ‌​ラーメッセージを拾って検索キーワードに含‌​める。もちろんswiftやiosと言った‌​2語は常に含めた方が良いでしょう。
  (ただ‌​し、「検索エンジンの上位に来る」のと「そ‌​れが正しいあるいはベスト」かどうかは無関‌​係なのでご注意を。)
- 折に触れて公式ドキ‌​ュメントも参考にする。
  (英語版しかありま‌​せんが、単語さえわかれば読み解ける平易な‌​表現です。)

検索エンジン・QAサイト・‌​そして教本と、利用できるものはなんでも利‌​用して、素晴らしいアプリを作成されること‌​を期待しております。

Comment: 教本の通り写していましたが、今回の場合教えて頂いたコードでやったほうがよさそうです！このようなことは自分で調べるべきなのですが、こんなに丁寧に教えていただけるなんて本当に感謝です。おかげで一週間で挫折などということにはならなそうです（笑）。もう一度自分でも復習してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました！

Comment: こちらこそ最後までご丁寧にありがとうございます。自分でも事前の調べを怠り、すぐこのサイトに頼ってしまったこと反省しています。本サイトを使うのは今回が初めてでしたので調べるコツまで教えていただいてとても感謝しています。OOPerさんの回答が無駄にならないようにアプリを完成させたいと思います！またの機械があったらよろしくお願いいたします。